# insert the same image on every other page

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I am creating a booklet and want to include a small image on every odd page. To do that, use master pages, right? But here's the catch - I want to rotate and move the image just a little as the pages progress to make the image look like it's jumping.  The image is a little man.)  I could just copy the same image on every page and guess at it's location, but I'm wondering if there is a feature that let's you place it in the exact same spot on each page.  Master pages won't work because I want to move each one. Any suggestions? I am using Indesign CS5. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Copy, move to the page you want the image on, and then Edit > Paste in Place

This positions the (pasted) image in the exact location it was copied from using to the page margins for positioning. This means if an image is sitting on a right facing page, it will paste in the same location (right page). Paste positioning is absolute not relative. So you would need to copy an image from the left page to left pages and then copy an image from the right page to other right pages.

For a non-facing page document, each paste will be in the same location for all pages.

Answer (score 2):

Counterintuitive as it may seem, the master page is your best bet. I'll assume you're working on a book and have facing pages. If not, I really recommend doing so—this will make your master page a spread as well.

Paste a version of your object on your master page spread, in the location you want it on the first relevant page. It might be advisable to create a separate master for the pages on which you want this image to appear. Otherwise you'll have to remove it from a lot of pages.

This takes care of the first image. For each subsequent one, go to the specific page and <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd></kbd> / <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd></kbd> it. This 'jumps' the master page item and makes it editable. The rest of the page will still follow the master. Transform and move the item as you wish.

Rinse and repeat with the other images.